# Will all Jews speak Hebrew when Mashiach comes?

Tags: hebrew, am-yisrael-jewish-nation, messiah, language

This question just kind of popped into my head, so I'm not sure whether it is really a good question for this site, but I wonder if anybody has written about it.

I would imagine that since when mashiach comes, all of Klal Yisrael is supposed to return to Eretz Yisrael, and since everybody living together would need to be able to communicate, and since the uniting language of the Jews is Hebrew, all of the Jews will speak Hebrew. Has anybody written about this idea? Will differences in dialects be resolved?

Comment: דאָך זיי וואָלט אַלע רעדן ייִדיש

Comment: @Double AA, Ha Ha, But youre yiddish could be improved. Doch zai volten ale gevolt noch alts reden yiddish.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Tzefanya 3:9](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16202/jewish/Chapter-3.htm#v9) states:

> כי אז אהפך אל עמים שפה ברורה לקרא כלם בשם ה' לעבדו שכם אחד
>
> For then I will convert the peoples to a pure language that all of them call in the name of the Lord, to worship Him of one accord.

The [Metzudos there](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%A2%3a%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%A6%D7%A4%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%94_%D7%92_%D7%98) explains that "a pure language" refers to Loshon Kodesh, which even the gentiles will change to speak in when Moshaich comes. Seemingly all the more so, this would be the universal language for Jews.

Comment: Does he mean non Jews as well.

Comment: @shulem Yes, he is clearly understanding the posuk to be referring to non-Jews as well. (You can click on the linked Metzudos to see it inside).